# How can we automatically start the azure agent in a self hosted Ubuntu VM

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-linux

I have installed an azure agent on a self hosted linux VM as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) & like to start the agent (i.e., trigger ./run.sh) when the VM is started everytime.

Comment: The documentation includes a section on running as a service. Please review it more closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the agent as a [systemed service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-systemd-service).

> If your agent is running on these operating systems you can run the
> agent as a systemd service:
>
> Ubuntu 16 LTS or newer
>
> Red Hat 7.1 or newer